# Неверный SQL запрос

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Всем привет! Опишу суть проблемы есть некая база данных (таблица книг) и надо сделать поиск по определенному параметру даной таблицы....делаю к примеру запрос поиска по имени:

```
MyBaseConnector = new SqlConnection(MyAdress);
MyBaseConnector.Open();
SqlCommand MyFindComand = null;
                string MyParam = "";
                MyParam = MyFindParam;
                if (NameFinder == true)
                {
                    MyFindComand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Autor,Year,Number,Tags,Count,ForBorrow,PdfAvailable FROM [Books] WHERE Name = Тарас Бульба", MyBaseConnector);
                }
  try
{
TableReader = MyFindComand.ExecuteReader();     
}
   catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (TableReader != null)
                        {
                            TableReader.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

Данный код вызывает следующую ошибку: {"Incorrect syntax near 'Бульба'."} .... тоесть неверно сформирован запрос или что не пойму:).(Первая моя программа с использованием БД в C# так что прошу помочь новичку).Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Все значения по сути читаются до пробела, если у вас `Тарас бульба`, то это как бы два значения и получается, что база не понимает, что такое `Бульба`. Если надо передавать что то с пробелами, то заносите это в кавычках, тогда система будет считать это одним целым.

Comment: Вообще то любые строковые значения должны быть в кавычках, не зависимо от наличия пробелов

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думаю, что в c sharp особые правила к оформлению sql запросов, поэтому мне кажется проблема в следующем.

При поиске по столбцам со строковым типам необходимо оборачивать строки в `''`,  то есть ваш запрос будет выглядить следующим образом

```
"SELECT Name, Autor,Year,Number,Tags,Count,ForBorrow,PdfAvailable FROM [Books] WHERE Name = 'Тарас Бульба'"
```

Также если вы ищите четко по данной строке, то используйте `=`, иначе пишите через шаблоны `WHERE Name like '%Тарас Бульба%'`, `%` - означает какой-то набор символов. [К ознакомлению](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Спасибо!Возьму на заметку.

Comment: Можна еще один вопрос..... не пойму почему даный код у меня всегда вызывает false если например добавить цикл while в блоке try и написать к примеру   while (TableReader.Read()) {..........}

Comment: @Baba_Jaga Если у вас новый вопрос - то нужно оформлять его отдельно, а не писать в комментариях.

Comment: @AK уже задал)...извините за данный казус